# Unable to get the file size of PNG image in R

Tags: r, image

I am trying to build a CNN model for Image classification in R, but because my train Data is huge (1.7 GB https://www.kaggle.com/c/plant-seedlings-classification/data), I am trying to read thru all the files and get their file size information in a data frame, so that I can remove the heavy images from the train data set within the code. Below is the snippet of the sample code :

```
      #Block 1 : creating a data frame of all the subfolder and image file in them 
      df_trainfiles <- data.frame(ID=numeric(),foldername=character(),filename=character(),filesize=numeric(),stringsAsFactors = F)
      df_testfiles<-data.frame(ID=numeric(),foldername=character(),filename=character(),filesize=numeric(),stringsAsFactors = F)

      df_train<-data.frame(info=character(),stringsAsFactors = F)
      df_test<-data.frame(info=character(),stringsAsFactors = F)

      trainDataPath<-"C:/Users/chiragrawal/Desktop/Learning/1. Kaggle/0.2 Plant Seedlings Classification/train/train"
      lsSubfolder<-list.files(path = trainDataPath,pattern = )

      for (intX in 1:length(lsSubfolder)){
        lsfiles<-list.files(path = paste0(trainDataPath,"/",lsSubfolder[intX]))  
          for(intY in 1:length(lsfiles)){
          df_trainfiles[nrow(df_trainfiles)+1,]<-list(nrow(df_trainfiles)+1, lsSubfolder[intX],lsfiles[intY],file.size(paste0(trainDataPath,"/", df_trainfiles[i,2],"/", df_trainfiles[i,3],sep="")))
        }
      }
```

When I look into the **df_trainfiles** after running the code, the field for file size shows **"N/A"**. I have tried few other methods, I found in other forums but none of the solution worked.

Your help is highly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: `file.size` wil return `NA` if the path you provide does not match an existing file. Did you check that the paths you build with `paste0` are correct?

Comment: Yes, I checked and paste0 result is correct, infact when I try to read the image, I am able to do it
`readImage(paste0(trainDataPath,"/", df_trainfiles[i,2],"/", df_trainfiles[i,3],sep=""))`
But only the file.size return "N/a"

Comment: I applied `file.size` on the files that I download from the [Signal Processing Group page](https://vision.eng.au.dk/plant-seedlings-dataset/) and I got no missing value. My command was `file.size(dir("Nonsegmented", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE))`.

Comment: Have you tried using `file.info` and see if there is a similar problem with other fields?

Comment: I tried to use the same command as you, and the result i get is **"numeric(0)"**

Comment: @Rohit Yes, I tried using file.info and yes, similar problem exists for all the other fields. The thing that surprises me is that I am able to read the pixel information of the mage using readImage function but not the size.

Comment: I only get numeric(0) if the folder does not exist in my current working directory, so I think you really should check again if the path to your data is correct.

Comment: I think you're using the row from `df_trainfiles` before it has been written. Try using the original variables `lsSubfolder[intX]` and `lsfiles[intY]`. Edit: I don't see where `i` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to not use a `for` loop, because more robust methods exist to list files and read their features.

Here is a proposition:

```
trainDataPath <- "C:/Users/chiragrawal/Desktop/Learning/1. Kaggle/0.2 Plant Seedlings Classification/train/train"
f <- list.files(path = trainDataPath, pattern = "png", recursive = TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
filename <- list.files(path = trainDataPath, pattern = "png", recursive = TRUE)
foldername <- sapply(strsplit(filename, "/"), "[", 1)
filesize <- file.size(f)

df_trainfiles <- data.frame(foldername, filename, filesize, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: I got a little carried away with the folder name, but it's fixed now.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and also, i learned a away to do this without loop.
Thanks a lot Sir!